# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:. Required by: project :app Add google Maven repository and sync project Open File

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

i am using latest android studios and facing some build issue. could you guys please help out

gradle updation, maven updation, andriod unistall and after installation also checked
i have follow stackflow answer but these all are old answer, so could you pls provide me exact solution i am begineer also. thanks in advance

Comment: Show your `build.gradle` file from project (not the app level one)